# Java ColourPicker as Background

Tags: java, android, background-color, color-picker

Hope you all doing good. I have a requirement in which i should set ColorPicker's Colors as a Background for My Android Layout Screen. i.e I need the following Colors with the same order as my Background Color.

[image]

I know i can make this Image as a Background for my layout But that isn't what i needed.

Kindly Anyone let me know is it possible to do Programmatically in Java.Thanks.